# Difference between junos-host zone and a security zone

Tags: juniper, security, juniper-junos, juniper-srx, traffic

As far as security zones are concerned, we apply policies to it to control the transit traffic.
And we also apply host-inbound-traffic to a zone or interfaces.
If we have both of the above configurations, why there is junos-host zone to prevent the traffic destined to the device itself as "host-inbound-traffic" also does the same thing.
Please help to correct me if im wrong somewhere or am missing something.

This whole concept of junos-host zone and security zones along with policies is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Junos-host zone can be used to add an additional check for traffic
>   destined to SRX. If you don't configure any security policy to-zone
>   junos-host, the traffic/packet will be validated based on
>   `host-inbound-traffic` configured under security zones. If you
>   configure security policy to-zone junos-host, that policy check will
>   be done additionaly to host-inbound-traffic/services specified under
>   zones.
>
> For example, if you allow SSH/Telnet/OSPF under interface
>   ge-0/0/0.0, but configure a security policy to-zone junos-host
>   allowing SSH, then Telnet/OSPF wont work. Only SSH will work.

More to read:
[Link-1](https://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/Junos-host-zone-clarification/td-p/270990)
[Link-2](https://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/JUNOS-HOST-zone-vs-lo0-filter/td-p/146916)

[image: Juniper SRX traffic flow]

Inbound packet will pass in this order:

1. Input interface filter, if set
2. Zone `host-inbound-traffic`
3. Zone-to-Zone policy

If traffic passed on 1 step, it can be still denied on 2 or 3.
Assume:

1. No interface filter applied
2. `host-inbound-traffic` set to `system-services ssh`
3. Policy from zone **zone1** to-zone **junos-host** allows only ICMP ping

As result, not ICMP ping, not SSH will be allowed. ICMP ping will be dropped on step 2; SSH will be dropped on step 3.

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong. If security policy to-zone junos-host is configured, its applicable to the whole device(all the interfaces included). So even if, host-inbound-traffic is configured for an interface or a zone(say Red-zone, allow only ssh) but the junos-host is configured to allow only ping, then it means the interfaces part of that Red-zone cannot allow ssh as the junos-host is configured to allow only ping to those interfaces.

Comment: `junos-host` it's device itself. So yes, if you will configure policy from some zone, lets say **RED** to junos-host, and you will allow only ICMP ping, but your **RED** zone host-inbound-services will have ICMP ping and SSH - only ICMP ping will be allowed. You can think of it like consecutive levels of security. Let me check some docs, I will edit my answer with traffic flow sequence...

Comment: Understood. Its all about levels and junos-host isnt given any priority over the host-inbound-traffic. And yes, please attach any docs if you have, it would be very helpful.

Comment: @RRHS Check theese: [Security Policies Feature Guide for Security Devices](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/information-products/pathway-pages/security/security-policies-feature-guide.pdf), [KB24227](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB24227)

Comment: Just one more query. Are configuring security zones a necessity? And i have also read that there has to be a minimum of 2 security zones to be configured. But some of the devices which i have used have only 1(security-zone HOST) and VSRX has none. Could you please shed some light on it.

Comment: @RRHS Main feature of SRX devices - zone-based firewall and stateful inspections. So using zones and policies are required to implement that functionality. SRX can work in two modes: packet mode and flow mode. Packet mode required for some implementations (like MPLS) and converts device in stateless firewall. I've never had used it in packet mode, but probably if it's in use then you don't need zones.

Comment: @RRHS [KB30461](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB30461)